# Pandas, how do I append a prefix to all column name that start with a number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a lot of columns, more than 400, some of them have numbers at the beginning for column names, here is an partial list of column names:

```
nextday_open
nextday_movement
nextday_movement_direction
nextday_movement_amount
nextday_daytime_movement
nextday_daytime_direction
overnight_movement
overnight_direction
5days_running_std
5days_running_var
5days_diff_std
5days_running_med_diff
```

How do I append a prefix to all the columns that start with number?  It should look like this:

```
nextday_open
nextday_movement
nextday_movement_direction
nextday_movement_amount
nextday_daytime_movement
nextday_daytime_direction
overnight_movement
overnight_direction
col_5days_running_std
col_5days_running_var
col_5days_diff_std
col_5days_running_med_diff
```

I can't rename them individually as there are too many columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a regex:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"^(\d+)", r"col_\1")
```

If it starts with (`^`) one or more digits (`\d+`), capture those digits and replace it with `col_{digits}` where `\1` refers to the first capturing group, if any.